# MochaUI: 'A is null' when adding columns

Tags: javascript, mootools, mocha.js

I've just downloaded MochaUI, and I'm playing around trying to build an interface.

I've successfully created windows, but I'm having trouble when it comes to layouts with columns.

I've included all of the libraries in the same order as the demo, and this is in my init code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new MochaUI.Column({
    id: 'sideColumn1',
    placement: 'left',
    width: 200,
    resizeLimit: [100, 300]
    });
});
```

When run, no column is created and I get the error:

```
A is null
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't you need to first create a desktop to have a side panel?

```
... = function() {
MochaUI.Desktop = new MochaUI.Desktop();
MochaUI.Dock = new MochaUI.Dock();
new MochaUI .... etc etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise this was essential. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the html-file should also be

```
<div id="pageWrapper"></div>
```

which appear columns.